# Porting linux kernel on arm board

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I would like to learn Linux porting on boards.
I would be experimenting this on raspberry pi boards with linux_4.9 (DT Enabled).

What are minimum requirements to call board's init_machine up ? 
How will I debug this code flow before configuring early printk.?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks .!!

Comment: Actually earlyprintk available at very early stage and requires minimum efforts to port. Anyhow, even without it you can just write an assembly macro (debug_ll is the same) which put characters to uart tx port in polling mode

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please tell me what are the code sequences (.c and .S files )that it traverses to call board's init function ?

Comment: in arch/arm/kernel/debug.S, I found printascii, printch, debug_ll_addr etc...  individually what they are used for .... ? Which one of above will be more suitable for me  . ?

Comment: JTAG, Lauterbach are your best friends. @AlexHoppus, it's not early enough in many cases (when you have kernel decompressed, though it does not yet initialize early printk). Macros would help sometimes on some boards, otherwise you need to setup clocks and do pin control and pin muxing before use serial.

Comment: if the purpose is only studying the initialization procedure, you can use QEMU (which also supports emulating raspberry pi 2). With QEMU you can attach the GDB debugger and single-step every instruction. This is cheaper and more reliable than setting up JTAG (which is VERY complicated with recent ARM cores).